# Regarding adding Start day of week in Sql table

Tags: sql

Here is my code though

```
   Insert into Promotion
   (PromoNo, StartTime, EndTime, PromoPrice, StartDayOfWk, EndDayOfWk)
   values
   (11729, 12:00:00, 18:00:00, 31.90, SET DATEFIRST 1, SET DATEFIRST 5 )
```

my problem is that i have no idea how to key in the start day of week and end day of week without hard coding it

Comment: This is for which `DBMS` ?

Comment: off-topic: StartDayOfWk? what happened, ran out of ink for the last word?

Comment: On topic: Why would you want to change the start and end days of the week for each record? I'm guessing it's to only keep the record active between x and y days of the week. In that case, why not just store tinyints 1 - 7 in each column, and treat them always the same (1 mon, 7 sun, or whatever you want)

Comment: Opps sorry for late reply i have actually solve the issue. Thankyou